# After Effects Ratio Error When Using Puppet Tool

Tags: after-effects

After Effects is continuously giving the following error when I try to use the Puppet tool:

**After Effects error: zero denominator in ratio addition. (17::16)**

Any idea what could be happening or how I can get around this issue?

---

I just restarted my After Effects. Now everything works Perfect!!!

Comment: I've taken my best stab at trying to clarify your question, but if the solution I found doesn't work (or even if it does) it would be helpful if you included some more detail about what you are trying to do when you get the error.  As it currently stands, there wouldn't have been enough to go on if I hadn't gotten a lucky hit searching Google.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell for sure without more detail about your problem, but the final post in [this](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/830880) Adobe Community thread appears to be having the same problem.

It looks like they restarted After Effects and created a new Puppet Pin and Puppet effect and then copied over their animation keyframes.  Not sure why the problem would be happening, sounds like it is probably a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

I get that error too, this is clearly a bug as it appears only if you move your mouse under the comp area. I removed the puppet tool effect then used a new one and it solved my problem. no need to restart..